# segfault in a c++ program

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

count_words.h

```
#ifndef _count_words_h_
#define _count_words_h_

#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <map>

class CountWords {
    std::map<std::string, int> countWords;      
        public  :
            CountWords();
            ~CountWords();
            int getCountWord(const std::string& word) const;
            int addWord(const std::string& word);
            const std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& getMaxCountWord() const;
            const std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& getMinCountWord() const;
};

#endif // _count_words_h_
```

count_words.c

```
#include "count_words.h"

CountWords::CountWords() {}

CountWords::~CountWords() {}

int CountWords::getCountWord(const std::string& word) const {
        if(countWords.find(word) != countWords.end()) {
                return countWords.find(word)->second;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}

int CountWords::addWord(const std::string& word) {
        return ++countWords[word];
}

const std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& CountWords::getMaxCountWord() const {
    std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>> maxCountWords;
        int maxCount = 0;
        
    for(const auto& pair : countWords) {
            if(pair.second > maxCount) {
                    maxCount = pair.second;
            }
        }
        
    for(const auto& pair : countWords) {
            if(pair.second == maxCount) {
                    maxCountWords.push_back(pair);
            }
        }
        return maxCountWords;
}

const std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& CountWords::getMinCountWord() const {

}
```

parse_text.h

```
#ifndef _parse_text_h_
#define _parse_text_h_

#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>

class ParseText {
        std::list<std::string> words;
        std::ifstream file;
        static int currentWord;
        void openFile(const std::string& fileName);
        void parseFile();
        void closeFile();
        public  :
                ParseText() = delete;
                ParseText(const std::string& fileName);
                ParseText(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long long maxWords);
                ~ParseText();
                const std::string& getFirstWord() const;
        const std::pair<std::string, bool>& getNextWord() const;
                const std::string& getWordAt(int index) const;
};

#endif // _parse_text_h_
```

parse_text.c

```
#include "parse_text.h"

int ParseText::currentWord = 0;

void ParseText::openFile(const std::string& fileName) {
        file.open(fileName);
}

void ParseText::closeFile() {
        file.close();
}

void ParseText::parseFile() {
        if(!file.is_open()) {
                throw std::runtime_error("couldn't open file");
        }
        std::string word;
        while(file >> word) {
                words.push_back(word);
        }
}

ParseText::ParseText(const std::string& fileName) {
        openFile(fileName);
        parseFile();
}

ParseText::ParseText(const std::string& fileName, unsigned long long maxWords) {
        openFile(fileName);
        parseFile();
        if(maxWords < words.size()) {
                auto it = words.begin();
                std::advance(it, maxWords);
                words.erase(it, words.end());
        }
}

ParseText::~ParseText() {
        closeFile();
}

const std::string& ParseText::getFirstWord() const {
        currentWord = 0;
        if(words.empty()) {
                throw std::runtime_error("no words in the list");
        }
        return words.front();
}

const std::pair<std::string, bool>& ParseText::getNextWord() const {
    if(currentWord >= words.size()) {
        return std::make_pair(std::string(), true);
    }
    ++currentWord;
    bool isLastWord = (currentWord == words.size() - 1);
    auto it = words.begin();
        std::advance(it, currentWord);
    return std::pair(*it, isLastWord);
}

const std::string& ParseText::getWordAt(int index) const {
        if(index < 0 || index >= words.size()) {
                throw std::out_of_range("index out of range");
        }
    auto it = words.begin();
        std::advance(it, index);
    return *it;
}
```

main.c

```
#include "parse_text.h"
#include "count_words.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string inputFileName = "text.txt"; 
    std::string outputFileName = "result.txt"; 
    
    const ParseText parseText(inputFileName);

    CountWords wordCounter;

    const std::string& firstWord = parseText.getFirstWord();
    wordCounter.addWord(firstWord);

    while (true) {
        const std::pair<std::string, bool>& wordInfo = parseText.getNextWord();
        if (wordInfo.second) {
            break;
        }
        const std::string& word = wordInfo.first;
        wordCounter.addWord(word);
    }

    const std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& maxCountWords = wordCounter.getMaxCountWord();
    const std::list<std::pair<std::string, int>>& minCountWords = wordCounter.getMinCountWord();

    std::ofstream outputFile(outputFileName);
    if (outputFile.is_open()) {
        int wordNumber = 1;

        for (const auto& pair : maxCountWords) {
            outputFile << wordNumber << "\t" << pair.first << "\t" << pair.second << "\n";
            wordNumber++;
        }

        for (const auto& pair : minCountWords) {
            outputFile << wordNumber << "\t" << pair.first << "\t" << pair.second << "\n";
            wordNumber++;
        }

        outputFile.close();
    } else {
        std::cerr << "err" << outputFileName << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

there is such a program in c++. it should count the number of words in a text file and output the result in result.txt in the format №/tword/tcount/n. it seems that all functions are written correctly, but in main on the line `const std::pair<std::string, bool>& wordInfo = parseText.getNextWord()` crashes segfault. I can't figure out what this could be related to. according to the task, you can't change the description of functions, so i can't make the getNextWord() function return a value, not a link.
i would be very grateful if you could tell me what is wrong with my main.c file structure <:

i tried debugging the program and it seems that the error is in main, and not in the function itself, where the program crashes

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: so what can you change ?

Comment: Debugger will tell you exactly why the segfault happened, even in main. Please add the info here. Or you can try compiling the program with sanitizers enabled, that way the crash should have more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Not even your debugger, your C++ compiler will tell you exactly what the bug is. All modern C++ compilers should be flagging the obvious bug that results in this crash, if the compiler option to turn on warning messages is given. Does your C++ compiler show you any warning messages when it tries to compile this? What do they say?

Comment: A segfault should result in a core dump that you can load in your debugger to analyse the reason for the crash.

Answer (score 1):

what you wanted was to return a reference to the strings in the list to avoid copying, this is done by the following return type.

```
std::pair<const std::string&, bool>
```

this next abomination however creates a dangling reference to a pair on the function stack that creates a copy of the string in your list then it frees the string and dangles.

```
const std::pair<std::string, bool>&
```

to avoid such errors always do your testing using the following compiler flags, it should warn you of such problems and not compile bad code.

```
-Wall -Wetra -Wpedantic -fsanitize=address -g -O0
```

it is detecting a ton of errors in your code.

Comment: "this next abomination"  - really?

Comment: @nicomp it's calmly doing a lot of unwanted work then resulting in an error, i am not sure what to call it.